# Does anyone know what google news uses for their clustering algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

curious if anyone has insight into what algorithm google news uses to group like stories together? k-means? or something custom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is kind of difficult to find that out, I guess; but for now I found this good white paper on possible algorithms for Google News Personalisation suggestions. Have a look for yourself:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.80.4329&rep=rep1&type=pdf

The three algorithms covered here are:
(1) MinHash clustering
(2) Probabilistic Latent Semantic Indexing
(3) Covisitation

and some combinations.

Hope this information was helpful!

Comment: interesting paper, but the question was about how similar stories are clustered. The paper in your link seems to be about personalising recommendations to a particular user. So doesn't address the exact question?

Answer (score 1):

When Google launched Google News, they used to put a small section about the algorithms they used to group on "About Google News" page, there was a mention of "An advanced **[Bayesian Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network)**" and some other algorithms(no other algorithms names were mentioned!). That paragraph is now absent from the same page.